# Visual Studio 2012 - Content Window Tabs Not Remembered on Re-Start of VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My tabbed open documents are stuck on the same three files for over a month now.  When I save and close VS2012 the open files I was working on do not come back on restart.  I get the same three old files regardless.  I am assuming that the tab cache has issues or something and needs to be cleared, but don't know where to go for this.  Has anyone else run into this glitch?  Any solutions to refresh the tab'able items so this functionality works correctly again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been three weeks with no answers ... so I finally figured this out on my own.  I hate answering my own questions, but here it is:

The `SUO` file is where all the settings, startup project, and cached user options are kept.  With large projects there are times where the .suo file becomes corrupted or too large causing sluggish, or odd behavior with these options.  Case in point the outlier I ran into with my open classes not being remembered.

**Solution:**
Simply *delete* the `.suo` file.  Visual Studio will *create* a fresh one for you.  I did this and it solved the problem.

**NOTE:** if you do not see a .suo file in your *Solution's root directory* try showing `hidden files`.